# Увеличение значения объекта

Tags: javascript, объекты, таймер, setinterval

Есть три кнопки. По нажатию на первую кнопку запускается первый секундомер, по нажатию на вторую останавливается первый и запускается второй секундомер, а по нажатию на третью кнопку останавливается второй секундомер и выводится сумма секунд первого и второго секундомера. Никак не могу понять, почему в консоли выводится 0.

```js
    let button1 = document.getElementById('first');
    let button2 = document.getElementById('second');
    let button3 = document.getElementById('end');
    let time1 = {
        sec1: 0,
        timer1: null,
    };

    let time2 = {
        sec2: 0,
        timer2: null,
    };

    function yourTime(time, yourSec, yourTimer) {//функция подсчёта времени
        function tickTimer() {
            ++time.yourSec;
        }

        time.yourTimer = setInterval(tickTimer, 1000);
    }
    button1.addEventListener('click', function () {
        yourTime(time1, time1.sec1, time1.timer1);
        console.log('первая запись пошла');
    });
    button2.addEventListener('click', function () {
        clearInterval(time1.timer1);
        yourTime(time2, time2.sec2, time2.timer2);
        console.log('остановка первой, вторая запись пошла');
    });
    button3.addEventListener('click', function () {
        clearInterval(time2.timer2);
        let sec = time1.sec1 + time2.sec2;
        console.log('результат:'+sec);
    });
```

```html
<button id="first">1</button>
<button id="second">2</button>
<button id="end">3</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В исправленных местах добавлены комментарии:

```js
let button1 = document.getElementById('first');
let button2 = document.getElementById('second');
let button3 = document.getElementById('end');
let time1 = {
  sec1: 0,
  timer1: null,
};

let time2 = {
  sec2: 0,
  timer2: null,
};

function yourTime(time, yourSec, yourTimer) {
  function tickTimer() {
    ++time[yourSec]; 
    // если ключ является переменной, запись с точкой не прокатит - нужны [скобки]
  }
  time[yourTimer] = setInterval(tickTimer, 1000);
}
button1.addEventListener('click', function () {
  yourTime(time1, 'sec1', 'timer1'); 
  // В качесвтве параметров - сами ключи в виде строк, а не ЗНАЧЕНИЕ ключа time1.sec1
  console.log('первая запись пошла');
});
button2.addEventListener('click', function () {
  clearInterval(time1.timer1);
  yourTime(time2, 'sec2', 'timer2');
  console.log('остановка первой, вторая запись пошла');
});
button3.addEventListener('click', function () {
  clearInterval(time2.timer2);
  let sec = time1.sec1 + time2.sec2;
  console.log('результат:'+sec);
});
```

```html
<button id="first">1</button>
<button id="second">2</button>
<button id="end">3</button>
```

P.s. могут быть интересные сюрпризы, если не использовать getElementById или querySelector('#')... т.к. в таком случае создается глобальная переменная с таким названием))